# It is okay to have a conditions in a summation limit that depend on the current value of another summation

Tags: summation, notation

this is one of those things that I know how to do in a programming environment but not sure how it translates into mathematics. I'm trying to express a sum so that it is easily visible that certain elements can be seen to be equal. Here is the original sum:

$$
s=\sum_{\alpha = 0}^{3}\sum_{\beta = 0}^{3}M_{\alpha \beta}(\Delta x ^ \alpha)(\Delta x ^ \beta)
$$

where the greek characters are indices not exponents. Here is my reformulated version:

$$
 s =
 \sum_{\alpha=0}^{3}
  M_{\alpha\alpha}(\Delta x^\alpha)^2 +
 \sum_{\alpha=0}^{3}\sum_{\beta = \alpha + 1}^{3}
  (M_{\alpha\beta} + M_{\beta\alpha})
  (\Delta x^\alpha)(\Delta x^\beta)
$$

This would make sense in something like a for loop where the order of summation is clear, but I'm not really sure how to express it in the context of the summation symbols. As a specific question, could someone tell me if this is mathematically valid?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either of your sums and they are clearly identical. Changing the order of summation is not an issue when the sum is finite.

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you are asking now.:) Yes it's ok that $\beta$ is dependent on $\alpha$ the order of summation is actually well defined. if you look at how $\sum$ is defined as a limit of partial sums.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah that makes sense, it's just usually the order of addition doesn't matter, so $\sum_{a=0}^{2}$ would be the same as $\sum_{a=2}^{0}$. But just because two things are equal does not mean the notation denotes the same thing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** It's perfectly valid to treat *finite* sums in the same way as *for*-loops in programs. You can *multiple sums* reshuffle in the same way as you may reorganise *nested for-loops*.

> **Two hints:**
>
> - You mention that *certain elements are equal*. This is not obvious. If an element is 
>     $$M_{\alpha \beta}(\Delta x ^ \alpha)(\Delta x ^ \beta),\qquad 0\leq \alpha,\beta\leq 3$$
>     no two of them have to be equal. Maybe you mean *symmetrical with respect to indices* instead.
> - The reformulated expression
>
> \begin{align*}
>  s =\sum_{\alpha=0}^{3}
>   M_{\alpha\alpha}(\Delta x^\alpha)^2 +
>  \sum_{\alpha=0}^{3}\sum_{\beta = \alpha + 1}^{3}
>   (M_{\alpha\beta} + M_{\beta\alpha})
>   (\Delta x^\alpha)(\Delta x^\beta)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   is correct, but we can see that the double sum in (1) with $\alpha=3$ gives an inner sum equal to zero
>   $$\sum_{\beta = \mathbb{4}}^{3}
>   (M_{\alpha\beta} + M_{\beta\alpha})
>   (\Delta x^\alpha)(\Delta x^\beta)=0$$
>   since it is an *empty sum*. This corresponds precisely to a nested *for*-loop and a setting of the outer index variable so that  the inner *for*-loop is not executed.
>   \begin{array}{l}
> \text{sum} \leftarrow 0\\
> \text{for } \alpha \text{ in } (0:3) \,\{\\
> \qquad\text{for }\beta \text{ in } ((\alpha+1):3) \,\{\\
> \qquad \qquad\text{sum} \leftarrow \text{sum}+(M_{\alpha\beta} + M_{\beta\alpha})
>   (\Delta x^\alpha)(\Delta x^\beta)\\
> \qquad\}\\
> \}
> \end{array}
>
> You may observe that the inner loop is not executed when $\alpha=3$.

Therefore you would presumably change the outer *for*-loop to iterate from $(0:2)$ and in the same way you could *simplify* the reformulated expression to

\begin{align*}
 s =\sum_{\alpha=0}^{3}
  M_{\alpha\alpha}(\Delta x^\alpha)^2 +
 \sum_{\alpha=0}^{\mathbb{2}}\sum_{\beta = \alpha + 1}^{3}
  (M_{\alpha\beta} + M_{\beta\alpha})
  (\Delta x^\alpha)(\Delta x^\beta)
\end{align*}

Comment: That's very true, thank you for your insightful comment, I did mean that they are symmetrical with respect to their indices, i was mistakenly trying to convey that $M_{\alpha \beta}=M_{\beta \alpha}$ is a valid solution, but truly, it is not the only one. Thank you for pointing out the mistake in my formula, I thought I may have missed something, I suppose it is akin to double counting since the $M_{33}$ term is already in the first term.

Comment: You're welcome! Good to see, my answer was helpful.  :-)